# Lagom ConductR connection refused error

Tags: scala, sbt, lagom

I am new to lagom-sbt and I am trying to run the Lagom service bundle using ConductR.

I have added following **sbt-conductr** version in **plugins.sbt**

```
 addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.conductr" % "sbt-conductr" % "2.4.0")
```

Here what I have run so far

```
sbt 
sandbox run 2.0.8 
install 
bundle:dist 
project <my-service-impl>
conduct load <bindle_zip>
```

Here are logs :-

```
|------------------------------------------------|
| Starting ConductR                              |
|------------------------------------------------|
Network address aliases are required so that the sandbox can operate as a cluster of machines.
To add the network aliases sudo privileges are required.
sudo ifconfig lo:0 192.168.10.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 up
```

The error I am getting while running the above commands :-

> Error: Unable to contact ConductR.
>
> Error: Reason: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=9005): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/bundles (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
>
> Error: Start the ConductR sandbox with: sandbox run IMAGE_VERSION

Can anyone tell why I am getting this error. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the command that has been mentioned in the [lightbend documentation](https://www.lightbend.com/product/conductr/developer):

> sandbox run **2.1.12** -n 3 --feature visualization

instead of using the **sandbox run 2.0.8** as above.

Make sure that you have extended `ConductRApplicationComponents` with `load(context: LagomApplicationContext)` method in your `Loader.scala` file.

Hope it helps!!